# Symfony2: How to properly include assets in conjunction with Twig template inheritance?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assets, symfony-2.1

I'm currently developing a web application using Symfony 2.1.0.

I've read through the [Templating chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) of the book and I'm trying to include assets (right now, it's just a single stylesheet) in my web pages.

I'm using the [Three-level inheritance system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance) that is mentioned in the book, and my application structure currently looks like this:

- **app/Resources/views/**

  - *base.html.twig:* base template, containing *title*, *stylesheets* and *body* blocks.
- **src/My/PageBundle/Resources/views**

  - *layout.html.twig:* layout template (extending the base template), appending the main stylesheet to the *stylesheet* block, and overwriting the *body* block, including *navigation.html.twig* and defining a *content* block
  - *layout-admin.html.twig:* same thing as above, but including *navigation-admin.html.twig*
  - **src/My/PageBundle/Resources/views/Main**

    - standard templates, extending the layout template and overwriting its *content* block
  - **src/My/PageBundle/Resources/views/Administration**

    - administration templates. Same thing as above, but extending the administration layout template.
- **src/My/PageBundle/Resources/public/css**

  - *main.css:* main stylesheet

As you can see, I have put the stylesheet in my bundle. I don't know whether this is good practice or not.

Now, the thing is, in layout.html I added this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/main.css)' }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

But `asset('css/main.css')` is just linking to `/css/main.css`, whereas `./app/console assets:install` installs the assets in `web/bundles/mypagebundle/`. I don't like the fact that this way, my bundle name would be publicly visible (which could make users suspect I'm using Symfony, and I like keeping the internals of my webpage, well, internal). Is it possible to change the directory where `assets:install` would install the assets? It seems tedious to me to manually install the assets in web/.

I'm also thinking about using Assetic for asset management, as I personally like the possibility to automatically minify my scripts/stylesheets and store them all together in one file. However, I hear that this is not possible if you include stylesheets at different levels, i.e. it wouldn't work with the three-level inheritance system. Is it possible to work around that? Also, would using Assetic enable me to hide my bundle name from the public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using assetic would address all your issues.

> I hear that this is not possible if you include stylesheets at different levels, i.e. it wouldn't work with the three-level inheritance system

You can, but it will generate a css file for each level (just like with asset(), actually).

Example:

layout:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets 'main.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

sub-template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets 'sub.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

result:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
```

Alternatively sub-template can completly override the stylesheets block, so that only one stylesheet is generated (but it's less dry):

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'main.css' 'sub.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

result (in production / non debug):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
```

Comment: So it is in no way possible to have Assetic glue all stylesheets at all levels together? Because with the second method, I would have to change ALL sub-templates if I decide to add another stylesheet at top level, right?

Comment: Right. You could also define the 'main' asset in config.yml (see docs) and reference this asset instead of referencing main.css directly. This way you can change the main asset without having to change all templates.

Comment: Thank you. On a side note, does the rest of my application structure look like good practice to you or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: looks like usual structure :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I wasn't quite sure on, for example, where I'd put the stylesheets as I can't yet distinguish between the application as a whole and my bundle. I'd upvote if I could (but I can't, sorry)