# How to reference named Assetic assets in a Twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

AsseticBundle gives a possibility to define named assets [in the Symfony's configuration file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html). How can I reference them in Twig templates, with `{% javascripts %}` and `{% stylesheets %}` Twig tags?

[Symfony's own Assetic documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) mentions only special notation for `@BundleName/Resources/file.cs` to include bundle assets, but tells nothing about the named assets.

Question [Symfony2: How to properly include assets in conjunction with Twig template inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449218/symfony2-how-to-properly-include-assets-in-conjunction-with-twig-template-inher) has a short mention in the comments that this is possible, but does not tell how to do it.

Using only the asset's given name (like `jquery` in the [Assetic's own Readme](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic#asset-manager)) does not work. Assetic tries to look the file `web/jquery` that apparently does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short version:**
Use "@name" in your templates:

**The longer version:**

If your assetic configuration looks like this :

```
[config.yml]
assetic:
    assets:
        bootstrap_css:
                inputs:
                    - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
                    - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css
        jquery_ui_css: 
            ....
```

Now you can use this in your templates, for example in your base.html.twig

```
<html><head>
...
{% stylesheets output='compiled/main.css'
    "@bootstrap_css"
    "@jqueryui_css"
    ...etc
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
</head></html
```

This one also defines that all css that is in there should be concatenated into one main.css file in the compiled directory.